# How to manually connect to my web server and send a TLS handshake with a hostname, followed by the HTTP request headers with a different hostname

Tags: tls, apache-http-server, headers

My Apache web server logs suffer from the dreaded error:

```
[ssl:error] AH02032: Hostname www.example.com provided via SNI and
 hostname example.com provided via HTTP are different
```

[I know what it means and why it happens](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134021/what-kind-of-attack-is-prevented-by-apache2s-error-code-ah02032-hostname-prov).

I need to manually reproduce the error in my logs. So that is what I'm asking.

How can I do it?

To be slightly more specific, I need to see if my web server upgrade still logs these incidents, and if so, take action to filter them from my log file.

This much I know: I need to send a hostname in the TLS handshake, e.g. `www.example.com`, to my web server (SNI should be handled automatically by the web server). Then send a different hostname, e.g. `example.com`, in the HTTP header.

I'm comfortable with telnet / openssl, etc., but don't know where to begin figuring out the commands.

#### First attempt at doing this:

I'm getting close, but for some reason the error is different and only appears the first time:

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect www.example.com:443

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> [ENTER]
```

```
[Sat Mar 05 17:31:35.958118 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 512:tid 139776568080128]
[client 10.0.0.100:37982] AH02032: Hostname www.example.com provided via SNI
and hostname example provided via HTTP have no compatible SSL setup
```

Notice the second hostname is `example`, even though I typed in `example.com`

#### Second attempt at doing this:

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect www.example.com:443

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> [ENTER]
```

Nothing reported in the log file, neither on the old server or new. I'm sending a different SNI hostname (I think) than HTTP hostname, so maybe the openssl client autocorrected, which is what I'd expect?

Comment: Good work with all of this and this self-answered question posting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `servername` flag was the difference.

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect example.com:443 -servername www.example.com

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
[ENTER]
```

Apache 2.4.6:

```
[Sat Mar 05 18:13:23.217568 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 22316] AH02032: Hostname
 www.example.com provided via SNI and hostname example.com provided via HTTP
 are different
```

Apache 2.4.52 does not produce this error in the log file.

Also, `man openssl-s_client` was helpful.